# Where is the best place to put the javascript inside React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 3 options. The difference is where my javascript code is located.

First (inside return):

```
export default function App() {

    return (
        <div>
            {/* Some javascript code */}
            <p>I am a paragraph</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Second (before return):

```
export default function App() {

    {/* Some javascript code */}

    return (
        <div>
            <p>I am a paragraph</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Third (inside useEffect):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {  
    useEffect(() => {/* Some javascript code */}, [])
    return (
        <div>
            <p>I am a paragraph</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I do not know if this will change the answer, but my real javascript code is this:

```
//This is a simple code to display the window width
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function Example() {
    
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => setWidth(window.innerWidth) )
    }, [])

    return <p>{width}</p>
}
```

Comment: Note - the `useEffect` should **return** a function that will run when the component unmounts and there you should unbind the `resize` event attached to the `window`.

Comment: Also note - you might want to use the [ReasizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) rather than the `window.resize` event. You can Google a hook for *resizeObserver* and simply use that hook to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first (inside `return`) and second (before `return`) example have the same effect: the code runs on first render and **every re-render**.

In the third (inside `useEffect`) example, the code only runs **once on first render**.

`useEffect` with empty dependency array acts similar to class-based component method `componentDidMount`.

If you need something like `addEventListener` or fetching data from outside API only for first render, it's a better idea to wrap them inside `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

Options with useEffect is fine, just return unsubscribe function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const resizeCb = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth)

    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCb)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeCb)
}, [])
```